# Boolean operations consistently producing weird results

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have two cubes. One is 6x6x6 and the other one is 4x4x4. I am careful to ensure that the normals are properly facing outward and that the scale and location has been applied. Yet no matter what I try and do, the boolean union seems to fail.

[image: boolean error]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your bottom faces seem coinciding, Booleans don't like coplanar faces, it can't figure out what way is in what is out.

Comment: Ok it was failing when I used the BMesh solver. When i switched to carve it worked fine. So frustrating! LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the boolean operations produce a clean topology use a ***BoolTool add on***. Download it from the net and activate it via *User Preferences* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>).
[image]

Select the first cube, then the second one, go to the *BoolTool* bookmark of the *Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) and press the *Union* button (under the *Direct* header). I suggest you to use this add on since it produces a cleaner geometry according to the regular blender's *boolean modifier*.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Blender's *Boolean* operations are still lacking a lot. There isn't really anything that you can do about this. I do believe that there was some kind of add-on that fixed a lot of issues but I can't remember the name.

*Maybe* the *Boolean* operation within *Edit Mode* could give you better results. To do this (be in *Edit Mode*) press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> and search *Boolean*. Choose the Boolean in *Edit Mode* option. Here is the official documentation: [Link](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Modeling)

Comment: Nils, I get "modifiers cannot be applied in edit mode"....

Comment: No, No. Sorry for no explaining properly. First of delete the modifier. Next select the two cube and press Ctrl+J. Then enter edit mode and select the smaller. Then press spacebar and search boolean and select it. If this does nothing try do this with th bigger one.